# Is this a valid Set-Cookie syntax

Tags: ssl, cookies, header, http-headers, setcookie

I find a `Set-Cookie` header which I need to know if it is valid syntax or not.

```
SessionId=ccc; path=/; HttpOnly, Secure; HttpOnly
```

My questions mainly are:

1) Is it valid to use comma before the directive `Secure`?

2) Is the directive `Secure` always preceded by a cookie value in the form of `x=y`? I mean the order. Can the directive `Secure` comes before the equation? or without equation?

I am at loss and either the above header is misconfigured or I am wrong. From my understanding of the Set-Cookie header syntax in Mozilla site [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) the directive Secure should always be preceded by a semicolon, then space, as in: `; Secure` after the word Secure, there can be either a semicolon `;` or it is the end of line. Please, clearify, I need accurate answer to write  a regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this RFC document you will find detailed information on the grammar set cookie: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#page-8